# Having trouble with a List-loop

Tags: python

Basically, you input the names and they are saved to the list. Say I input "a, b, c, d and e. After printing the list it comes out with "a, a, a, a, and a"

Then, when it asks if the student has paid or not, it doesn't matter what value you input, the name won't be moved to the designated list.

```
name_list = []
count = 0
name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
while count < 5:                        #CHANGE BACK TO 45 
  name == raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
  name_list.append(name)
  count = count + 1 
print "List full"
print name_list

paid_list = []
unpaid_list = []

for names in name_list:
  print "Has " + name + " paid? Input y or n: "
  input == raw_input()
  if input == "y":
    paid_list.append[input]
    name_list.next
  elif input == "n":
    unpaid_list.append[input]
    name_list.next

print "The students who have paid are", paid_list
print "The students who have not paid are", unpaid_list
```

Comment: Why di yiy wrute `name_list.next`?

Comment: I suggest you learn the difference between `=` and `==`in Python

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
name_list = []
count = 0
name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
while count < 5:                        
  name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
  name_list.append(name)
  count = count + 1 
print "List full"
print name_list

paid_list = []
unpaid_list = []
for names in name_list:
  print "Has " + names + " paid? Input y or n: "
  input = raw_input()
  if input == "y":
    paid_list.append[input]
  elif input == "n":
    unpaid_list.append[input]
```

Note: `raw_input()` is not there in python 3.x. Instead use: `input()` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)).

Answer (score 0):

Your populating loop is:

```
name_list = []
count = 0
name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
while count < 5:                        #CHANGE BACK TO 45 
    name == raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
    name_list.append(name)
    count = count + 1
```

You first assign the value received through `raw_input` to `name`.

Then, for `count` from `0` to `4`, you check if `name` is equal to the input, and then, append it to `name_list`.

Instead of **checking the equality** by writing `name == raw_input(...)`, what you want is to **assign** the input value into `name`.

Therefore, you mustn't use `==`, but `=`.

Your loop should be:

```
name_list = []
count = 0
name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
while count < 5:                        #CHANGE BACK TO 45 
    name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
    name_list.append(name)
    count = count + 1
```

Now here is a more Pythonic way:

```
names_list = []        # there are more than one name in the list
for _ in range(5):     # the loop index is not needed, so I use the anonymous underscore
    name = raw_input("Enter the student's name: ")
    names_list.append(name)
```